# How would I make it so the output will round up to two decimal places?

Tags: java, netbeans, decimal

My code here is working fine but whenever I run it, it doesn't seem to round up and I don't know what to add and where to add it.

```
package com.mycompany.billofsale;

public class Billofsale {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double s = 12.49;
        double p = 20.00;
        double t = 0.13;
        double result = s * t;
        double result2 = s + result;
        double result3 = p - (s + result);
        System.out.println("The total is "+s
                + "\n The tax is "+result
                + "\n The total cost with tax is "+result2
                + "\n The change is "+result3);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, never use `double` for money. Use whole integer numbers, or use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use DecimalFormat to format all the numbers that you want to print to the decimals that you want.

Try with this code:

```
double s = 12.49;
    double p = 20.00;
    double t = 0.13;
    double result = s * t;
    double result2 = s + result;
    double result3 = p - (s + result);
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat(".00");
    format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println("The total is " + s + "\n The tax is " +format.format(result) + "\n The total cost with tax is " + format.format(result2)
            + "\n The change is " + format.format(result3));
```

Comment: It gives the error "Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: DecimalFormat"

Comment: You have to import the library, import java.text.DecimalFormat;

Comment: It still gives an error for the rounding mode part. It says "Cannot find symbol"

Comment: I forget the rounding mode library, import java.math.RoundingMode;

Comment: I don't know wich rounding mode do you want so I will let you a link about that: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html